# HaxeFlixel, Font gets fuzzy android upscale

Tags: android, haxe

I made a simple game for android with a small native resolution (320x480). When text gets upscaled it loses its sharpness. Tried having anti aliasing on and off and both results were fuzzy. The size of the text is 16 (read that with some fonts the size should be dividable by 8). Also tried different fonts, but had the same result. Any solutions to that?